# in ubuntu cpabe toolkit installation,

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

In cpabe toolkit installation, during the encryption of file using attributes it will not show any details regarding encryption, I got struck in this part,
home@ubuntu:~$ cd cpabe
home@ubuntu:~/cpabe$ cd cpabe-0.11

home@ubuntu:~/cpabe/cpabe-0.11$ cpabe-enc pub_key message.txt
(RIT_Organization and (Job_Doctor or Id_P1))

Answer (score 1):

The output of the command cpabe-enc when processed appropiately is just the ciphertext that will be message.txt.cpabe.  Now if you want more details about encryption, for exemple the computation of pairings, you can modify yourself the source file enc.c.

Hope this has helped you.